# Can I use speaker wire for stereo headphone?

Tags: cable

Can i make a stereo type plug with only 2 wires or will it only be mono?

I have seen pics of the female wall jack that only has 2 wires but is stereo sound. I am unsure if this is effective.

Answer (score 1):

No, you probably looked at a shielded twin pair cable like this one:

[image: shielded twin pair cable]

And that is actually four leads, not two.

A twin core cable like this one could also be used (it is only three leads as the shield is shared):
[image]